# Is it possible to make VIM emphasize found text?

Tags: vim, colors, search

As vim wiki's stated we can look up strings by using `*`. But by default, looked up string is not being emphasized. Is it possible to configure vim that the strings will be emphasized when looked up something like that:

[image]

Comment: Works for me; what colourscheme are you using?

Comment: Try `:set hlsearch`, but I think it is on by default.

Comment: @Leiaz Yes, you were absolutely right. Thank you. Might you provide an answer?

Comment: @Leiaz BTW When I press `#` and `*` it's not obvious which line is pointed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have search results highlighted, the option is `hlsearch`. According to the help it is off by default. So either use `:set hlsearch` or add it to your .vimrc.

The command `:nohlsearch` turns the highlighting off temporarily, until the next search.

To make the cursor position more obvious I also use `set cul` and `set cuc` to highlight the current line and column.